# ¿Cómo decodificar el siguiente texto en python?

Tags: python

Estoy intentando decodificar el texto de una contraseña de la siguiente manera:

```
pwd.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
```

El error es el siguiente:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position
> 5: invalid continuation byte

La contraseña es parecida a esta:

> b'v10Ra\xdaDLf\xf3-\x82/o\x8d\xda\x03@g
> \x8c%\x8c9\xbc\xf0\xa5\x1e\xdf\xa5\t'

También está codificada pero, no se decodificarla.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que la contraseña esté codificada en otro formato, como `UTF-16` o `ISO-8859-1` (existen multitud de formatos diferentes).

Por ejemplo, para decodificar utilizando ISO-8859-1`:

```
pwd.decode(encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

También puedes intentar decodificar la cadena de bytes utilizando diferentes opciones de manejo de errores (`errors`).

```
pwd.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
```